# VB.Net - how can i get the type of the object contained in an List

Tags: vb.net, ilist, gettype

If I have a list...

```
dim l as List(of MyClass) = new List(of MyClass)
```

and I want to get the type of the objects contained in the list, how do I do that?

The obvious answer, that doesn't seem to be possible from my actual implementation, would be to do something like this...

```
public function GetType(byval AList as IList(of GenericType)) as System.Type
  dim lResult as system.type = nothing
  if AList.Count > 0 then lResult = AList(0).GetType
  return lResult
end function
```

But what if the list is empty and I still want to know the type it contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good article on this at [MSDN, here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx)

Basically you can use GetGenericArguments() to get an array of the types provided as arguments to your generic type. In the case of a List, there's only one argument so you will get what you need using eg

```
dim l as List(of MyClass) = new List(of MyClass)
dim t as Type = (l.GetGenericArguments())(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift resopnse.  I've been wrapped up in this project - typical overly optimistic scheduling set by my client.  I was able to use your example in some LINQ.  The link the the MSDN article provided even more ideas.  It's turned out great.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it put a smile on my face :) If you've found my answer helpful, you can set it as the accepted answer by clicking the big tick to the left of it.